# Using stylo package in r

Tags: r

when I try to use stylo in R this Problem response comes up:

```
stylo()
using current directory...
 
GUI could not be launched -- default settings will be used;
otherwise please pass your variables as command-line agruments

Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] invalid command name "tk_chooseDirectory".
```

im pretty new to programming/ using R so I pretty much have no idea what the program tries to tell me... I tried to install it again, after that using `library("stylo")` and the `stylo()` function. the result should be that the stylo user interface pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a Mac?

If so, you might need to install XQuartz and XCode to enable your Mac to launch the user interface:

1. go to xquartz.org/, click on the XQuartz-2.8.5.dmg link to download XQuartz (the version number may be different; the website will always bring you to the link for the latest version)
2. Open Terminal, and run the following command to install XCode: `xcode-select --install`

On Windows, you may have to install RTools: download the installer from here: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html

Re-install the stylo package after you have installed XQuartz/RTools.